# form data: populating input tag with value from select option

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a html form, and I need to make the input value equal whatever is chosen as a select option (due to the way the form is processed, the value must be associated with an input tag - it won't work from within a select tag). Here are the select options in my form:

```
<select type="hidden" name="item_colour" id="select">
   <option value="yellow item" selected>yellow</option>
   <option value="blue item">blue</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to create a hidden input along these lines:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value=item_colour>
```

The above obviously doesn't work, and I'm thinking I need to somehow use the following javascript:

```
document.getElementById("item_colour")
```

But I'm stumped how to make it all work. Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering why you cannot use the select as a normal form element, understanding why may help us answer - maybe some of your code?

Comment: The form goes to a minicart script (which I didn't write), where it also sends a bunch of other attributes, including shipping weight. For reasons I don't understand, the weight value doesn't get parsed by the minicart script if the item_name value is set within a select tag, whereas it works fine if I set it within an input tag. The problem with that, is I can't select the item name from a dropdown list. Rather than try and modify the complicated minicart script, I thought it might be easier to work around it.

Comment: I find this very interesting linking the names to the form should just send it through as a HTML form request, unless this is all done via JS

Comment: It's mostly beyond my skill level, so I can only speculate what's going on. The form is just a html form, and I can only get the shipping weight to be associated with the item when the value is set using <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="yellow item">

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$( "#select option:selected" ).val();
```

Full example by creating and submitting a form via JS

```
function submit() {

                var form = document.createElement("form");
                form.method = "GET";

                 var obj = document.createElement("input");
                 obj.name = "item_colour";
                 obj.value =  $( "#select option:selected" ).val();

                 form.appendChild(obj);

                document.body.appendChild(form);

                form.submit();

            }
```

If this doesn't work then maybe the library you are using is changing the dom of the select. It's better if you inspect the element select through the browser and see how it is working. I would suggest to also use the console in the browser developer options, it will allow you to write javascript code right on the page which will help you in testing.

Another way of getting the selected attribute is via

```
 $('.my-custom-select').on('change', function (e, params) {
                alert(e.target.value); // OR
                alert(this.value); // OR
                alert(params.selected);
       });
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please provide a fuller explanation of how to implement this? Unfortunately my overall knowledge is too rudimentary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="$( '#select option:selected' ).val()">
```

Comment: This literally sends the item name as a string of text: $( '#select option:selected' ).val()